# My function returned some value in first time, after it didn't return anything (NaN)

Tags: javascript

I have a function, which will be always running when certain element is being dragged by the cursor of the mouse.

Inside of the function I have some values: `e.target` (element dragged of function event), `e.x` (client X), `e.y` (client Y), `x` and `y`.

Almost at the end of function I change the variable `x` value to this:

```
parseInt(
            parseInt(
                  parseInt(e.target.style.left)
                  +e.x
            )
           +Map.GetItemWidth(
                  Attribute(e.target,'data')
           )/2
)
```

And the `Map.GetItemWidth` function is this:

```
GetItemWidth:function(s){
        if(XML.GetRoot(s)==Map.Tags.S){

        /* If item root tag is equal to "S" */

              return parseInt(XML.Tag.Get(
              {
                    into: Map.Tags.S,
                    attr: Map.Attr.L
              },
              s));
              /* XML.Tag.Get([{[tag],[attribute]}],[string]) 
              returns a attribute of some tag in some XML string. */
        }
}
```

Quickly explaining, each element on document body has a attribute (data) that contains its XML tag (`<S><S /></S>`), the `<**S**></**S**>` tag make it represents a ground (of my tool), and the `<S />` tag contains its attributes with values about it (like X and Y coord, or width and height). They looks like this: `<S L="415" H="236" X="NaN" N="" Y="267" T="0" P="0,0,0.3,0.2,0,0,0,0" />`.

Now, If you did get it, please answer me explaining what I'm doing wrong.
The problem of the function is so:

When I start dragging some ground, the console returns its current XML `X` attribute and `L` (length, width), after return "NaN" for `X` (or... nothing?) and undefined for its `L` attribute.

Thank you so much.

Comment: nested ParseInt calls??

Comment: @epascarello Not sure because it works in first time. This started happening because I changed the method to get item's width (because I did this GetItemWidth() function), but I'll need it.

Comment: Well use console.log calls to debug what is going on inside. Something is not returning a number.

Comment: Well if the element does not match you return nothing....

Comment: @Errorever Missing `,` comma between first , second parameters to wrapper `parseInt() ` ? Is `parseInt()` that is first parameter to wrapper `parseInt()` expected to be added to `Map.GetItemWidth` ? Is `+Map.GetItemWidth` expected to convert `Map.GetItemWidth` to an integer ?

Comment: @epascarello It still shows that the `x` variable contains the "NaN" value, but I'll put more info in the question because I know that it's incomplete yet, just securing me if the energy stops.

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry! I didn't see your comment, let me see...

Comment: (aside from nested parseInts), I would bet that in your HTML element, the `style.left` is not explicitly set in style or in css class. And that the `parseInt(e.target.style.left)` generates `NaN`. Because `parseInt("")` = `NaN`

Comment: @wintvelt It's always set in the element. I'll try to test if the error is on this step and I'll say which was the result.

Comment: Well, basically, the error is in the `Map.GetItemWidth()` function, not a error, and yeah a problem*. I did some tests, probably I'll can solve it after many hours......!

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple thing that I forgot to specify, and sorry for the bad sense in the question (for missing more info).

Always that I was updating the element `data` attribute, I added the `<S [attributes] />` tag on, but I didn't make it between the `<S></S>` tag, so the `Map.GetItemWidth` wasn't returning anything because of the `if` conditional, in this line: `if(XML.GetRoot(s)==Map.Tags.S){`.

It's working well right now.

Thanks.